# How to handle multiple callbacks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can i handle multiple callbacks? Right now only the first one i register gets fired..

Here is my current code for handling the callbacks (this code is being loaded async)

```
var widget = function () {
    var onNameCallback,
    onTriggedCallback;    


    function getName(callback) {
        onNameCallback = callback;
    }

    function onTrigg(callback) {
        onTriggedCallback = callback;
    }


    /** lots of code ... **/


    if(typeof onNameCallback == 'function') {
        // Fire the callback
        onNameCallback('1');
    }   

    if(typeof onTriggedCallback == 'function') {
        // Fire the callback    
        onTriggedCallback('hello');
    }   


    /** lots of code ... **/    

    return {
       getName:getName,
       onTrigg:onTrigg,
    };
}();

if (window._test) {
    for (var i = 0; i < _test.length; i++) {        
        var method = _test.shift();
        try {
            widget[method].apply(widget, _test);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        var method = _test.shift();
    }
};
```

And here is how i register them:

```
_test.push('getName', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}); 

_test.push('onTrigg', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But for some reason only `getName` is fired..

Any ideas?

Comment: The way you set up your code, `_test` will contain the elements `['name', function, 'name', function]`. The code I wrote to one of your previous questions (which uses `shift`) was under the assumption that every element of `_test` is an array itself. To make it work with in your case, you would have to find the next method name in the array, remove all elements up to then and pass them as second argument to `.apply`, e.g. `_test.splice(0, index_of_next_method_name)`. If you only pass one argument to the method, that's not a problem, otherwise using an array of arrays is easier.

Comment: That method worked perfect until i had to add callbacks, but the above works with and without callbacks only prob is that i cannot use more than 1 callback

Comment: i see you shifting array `_.test` twice in for loop..

Comment: Would it be possible to use the "every call is an array within itself" method even though i am using callbacks? Would that solve so that both callbacks are fired?

Comment: @CodeJack that was only a quick fix to get the method name

Comment: It would make the code that process the `_test` array easier.

Comment: @FelixKling Not sure how to write those callbacks into arrays though

Comment: Like so: `['getName', function(data) {...}]`. A function is just like any other value. I think overall it would be easier for you if you read some JavaScript tutorials (e.g. http://eloquentjavascript.net/), so that you are familiar with these basics. It would be more fruitful than asking a bunch of SO questions (and wait for answers).

Comment: @FelixKling You are the man!! I managed to get the callbacks into arrays themselves and it works great now!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with the code is that you are counting `i` up while you are shifting items from the array so that the length of the array gets smaller. You will be looping through half of the items in the array. Instead just loop while there is anything left in the array.

Also, you are shifting the method name twice from the array and ignoring one (which actually is the handler), while you are using `apply` to call the method and sending all remaining items in the array as parameters. This actually doesn't keep the code from working, but it's hard to follow what it actually wants to accomplish. Shift both values from the array, and use the `call` method to call the method with a single parameter.

```
if (window._test) {
  while (_test.length > 0) {
    var method = _test.shift();
    var handler = _test.shift();
    try {
        widget[method].call(widget, handler);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Edit:

If you want to have each callback in an array, just shift that from the `_test` array:

```
if (window._test) {
  while (_test.length > 0) {        
    var callback = _test.shift();
    try {
        widget[callback[0]].call(widget, callback[1]);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the callbacks into arrays like:

```
_test.push(['getName', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}]); 

_test.push(['onTrigg', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}]);
```

And modified:

```
if (window._test) {
    for (var i = 0; i < _test.length; i++) {        
        var method = _test[i].shift();
        try {
            widget[method].apply(widget, _test[i]);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
};
```

Works great now!

Thanks FelixKling!